# Latest Xampp using mysql from Xampp version 1.4.4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, xampp

Is there any way that I can combine PHP from xampp version 1.8.2 with MySQL from xampp version 1.4.4?

That is PHP 5.4.16 and MySQL 4.0.13

Unfortunately, I have to use that version of MySQL for my project, and wanted the latest that I can work with CI.

I tried to run the latest Apache from xampp and the old MySQL but when I use `mysql_connect` I see the following error:

> Warning:
> mysql_connect(): Connecting to 3.22, 3.23 & 4.0 is not supported. Server is 4.0.13-  max-debug
>
> Warning:
> mysql_connect(): Connecting to 3.22, 3.23 & 4.0 servers is not supported

Any help would be appreciated, even if the answer says that it's not possible to combine the two.

Comment: are those on a same machine?

Comment: yes, i'm using windows

Comment: is there any force to use xammp?

Comment: nope, the point is i have to use mysql 4.0.13 and i wanted to use php, CI(for reusable purpose) that connect with my android app, i'm willing to use http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ for the connection

Comment: so why don't you use php and mysql separately? I think this will solve your problem. xammmp is good tool, but it is not customized to anyone's needs.

Comment: and by the way, did you try mysqli_connect or pdo?

Comment: yes, i can use only php as script, but i want it to work with latest CI then i can use it later.

Not yet, i'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't waste time combining old with new parts.

If you (i guess) need to re-use your old databases, just use the latest XAMPP verison and backup all your databases folders `XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/`, which you'll can move then into the new directory located in `XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/`.

they are just folders you can backup and re-use ;)

Comment: you're right it wasting time, i decided to use xampp 1.4.4(mysql 4.0 and php 4.3.7) and codeigniter 1.7.3 with this setting https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/MySQL-4.0 so i can work with the database.